# Multiline bash comment etiquette (#+)

Tags: bash

The [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html) makes extensive use of multiline comments in examples, of the form:

```
echo ls -l | sh
#  Passes the output of "echo ls -l" to the shell,
#+ with the same result as a simple "ls -l".
```

(found in the explanation for the pipe `|` symbol). Other multiline comments look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# rpm-check.sh

#  Queries an rpm file for description, listing,
#+ and whether it can be installed.
#  Saves output to a file.
# 
#  This script illustrates using a code block.
```

(example 3.2 in the linked page).

What is the ratonale for the use of `#+`? Some multiline comments it seems to indicate that the comment continues on in the next line, but others it doesn't.
Is there a 'bash-scripting comment etiquette` that I should (attempt to) follow in my own scripts?

Comment: What syntax are all the cool kids using? I joke, I don't like this it add confusion and clutter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that the author of the Advanced Bash Scripting Guide uses that on lines which continue a sentence from the previous line.

This is not a standard stylistic choice; this appears to be a stylistic quirk of the author of the Advanced Bash Scripting Guide.

I will note that while there is some good technical information in the Advanced Bash Scripting Guide, the coding style is fairly non-standard. I wouldn't use it as an example of what good Bash coding practices are. A somewhat better resource is the [Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ).